# How can I get a list of long Wikipedia articles?

Tags: wikipedia-api

I know [Special:LongPages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:LongPages) and I've seen https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php and https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/.

Is there a way to get long articles (or articles ordered by size) from one of the APIs?

Comment: what do you mean with long articles, the full page?

Comment: @rob.m Non-stub articles. Lets say at least 1000 characters without any formatting / headers / tables / lists / infoboxes.

Answer (score 0):

For many special pages, including LongPages, the API equivalent is the [querypage](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bquerypage) module:

```js
let query = {
  action: 'query',
  list: 'querypage',
  qppage: 'Longpages',
  format: 'json',
  formatversion: 2,
  origin: '*'
};
function doQuery( query ) {
  return $.get( 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php', query ).then( function ( data ) {
    console.log( data.query.querypage.results.map( function ( item ) {
      return item.title;
    } ) );
    if ( data.continue ) {
      let continueQuery = $.extend( {}, query, data.continue );
      return doQuery( continueQuery );
    }
  } );
}
doQuery( query );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you add https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=querypage&qppage=Longpages&format=json as an example?